# $A$ dense in $X$, $O$ open in $X$

Tags: general-topology

**Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, $A$ dense in $X$, $O$ open in $X$. Prove that $O \subseteq \overline{A\cap O}$.**

I stucked at some point, but tried this as follows:

Well Known Property: for any $A,B$ subsets of space $X$ we have $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq \overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$;
$\overline{A\cap O}\subseteq \overline{A}\cap\overline{O}=$(since $A$ is dense in $X$)$=X \cap\overline{O}=\overline{O}$. But if $O\subseteq \overline{A\cap O}$, then $\overline{A\cap O} =\overline{O} $, since $\overline{O}$ must be smallest closed set (w.r.t. set inclusion) containing $O$. I am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @ZhenLin it is true actually. You can find a proof here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Intersection_is_Subset_of_Intersection_of_Closures

Comment: @ZhenLin It's an inclusion, not an equality; for disjoint dense subsets, you get $\varnothing \subseteq X$, which is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definitions and standard strategies.

Since you have to prove an inclusion, pick any $x\in O$. You have to prove that $x$ is in the closure of something, so consider any open neighbourhood $U\ni x$ and you have to prove that the intersection of $U$ and that 'something' is not empty. That is, you have to prove that
$$U\cap O\cap A\neq\emptyset$$

But $O\cap U$ is a nonempty, open set because it is the interesection of open sets and $x\in O\cap U$. Since $A$ is dense, any nonpempty, open set intersects $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in O$, and let $U$ be an open set containing $x$. Then $U\cap O$ is a non-empty open set containing $x$, and hence
$$
(U\cap O)\cap A \neq \emptyset
$$
since $A$ is dense. Hence,
$$
U\cap (O\cap A) \neq \emptyset \quad\forall U \text{ open, with } x\in U
$$
Hence $x\in \overline{O\cap A}$, and so
$$
O \subset \overline{O\cap A}
$$